# Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.4.9:run (default-cli) on project myProject: Failure

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jetty

I am trying to run application which was working previously for me by Maven section in IntelliJ and click on `jetty:run` however now I see error:
`Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.4.9.v20180320:run (default-cli) on project myProject: Failure`.
This error is not helpful and I can't find some more useful stuff. I see that many steps are green: create, resources, compile, testCompile but it's failing at run.
How can I find some logs to investigate problem?

Comment: Does it work from command line?

Comment: The maven command line debug options should also help. (`-X` or `--debug`)

Comment: Thank you @JoakimErdfelt, indeed, I used -X option and saw that error is `address already in use`, something was already running on 8080. The most disappointing fact is that I updated IntelliJ Idea to 2020.2, before I used 2019.sth and it always thrown `address already in use` when it happend, that's why I didn't take into consideration such problem.